# Error in mysql SP with array parameter

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure for inserting data into the table. But now lets say, I want to insert multiple rows at the same time using the stored procedure. How can i go about it ?One way would be to use a loop but that would mean calling the stored procedure many times which is not efficient.This is what I tried but I keep receiving the following erro

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
       check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
       syntax to use near '?,?,?,@output); select @output' at line 1
```

p_insertarticleBEGIN

```
 insert into rsscontent (title,link,date,count) values (a_title,a_link,a_date,a_count);

    SET status = '001';
END
```

node js

```
var sql = "CALL p_insertarticle(?,?,?,?,@output); select @output";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1,2],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2,4],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3,5],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4,6]
];

con.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

Is there a way to insert multiple rows inside the stored procedure. I am using mysql and Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way on earth this will work.

Firstly, you are trying to pass an array or collection to a stored procedure which is expecting a single set of values.

Secondly, even if it were possible to pass in an array in this manner, your sql would indeed then be invalid. Multi-insert statements are done like this:

```
insert into rsscontent (title, link, date, count) 
values 
  (a_title,a_link,a_date,a_count),
  (a_title2, a_link2, a_date2, a_count2),
  (a_title3, a_link3, a_date3, a_count3);
```

And so on.

Using a stored procedure is overkill for this simple example. It would be better, and more maintainable to just build the sql statement dynamically in node.js and execute it right off the bat.

Something like this (pseudo-ish code, sorry I'm no js expert):

```
var sql = "insert into rsscontent (title,link, date,count) values";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1,2],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2,4],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3,5],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4,6]
];

for ( var x in values ){
    sql += "('" + val[x,0] + "', '" + val[x,1] + "', " + val[x,2] + ", " + val[x,3] + "),";
}
```

There's probably a neat way to use values.push and values.join to build the string a lot faster.
You also need to figure out how to remove the final trailing comma, which will invalidate the sql, and replace it with a semi-colon.

This is for a javascript whizzkid to figure out!

Comment: "remove the final trailing comma" use slice from 0 to arr.length - 1

Comment: Thanks @AndréDosSantos

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution myself and the best way I found was the following,I don't like it, but it works.

JS:

```
var values = "
('demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1,2),
('john', 'john@gmail.com', 2,4)";

'CALL p_insertarticle(?)',values
```

SQL:

```
IN values VARCHAR(5000)

set @sql = concat("insert into rsscontent (title,link,date,count) values ",values,"");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

As you can see above the values are passed as a string to the SP, and then just do a simple concat and execute the statement. This isn't a good practice.